# cleos push transaction always errors out with "Expired Transaction"

Tags: cleos

```
cleos push transaction --skip-sign '{"compression":"none","transaction":{"expiration":"2018-09-18T08:44:59","ref_block_num":2513,"ref_block_prefix":4093373029,"max_net_usage_words":0,"max_cpu_usage_ms":0,"delay_sec":0,"context_free_actions":[],"actions":[{"account":"eosio.token","name":"transfer","authorization":[{"actor":"bx.hotwallet","permission":"active"}],"data":"90558c8667da403f107034dcdcd4b2e3010000000000000004454f5300000000127769746864726177616c2066726f6d204258"}],"transaction_extensions":[]},"signatures":["SIG_K1_K1DM3k8TUaA6rhgDRhvgHYbfEFjnhYgyp5DScDimanprNKEd794C1D12wQpf1m2cJVVY7fqETaFvrQPxPdiMsiwF6SQNHx"]}'
Error 3040005: Expired Transaction
Please increase the expiration time of your transaction!
```

it is created using eosjs with expiration time 1 hour in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer on https://www.npmjs.com/package/eosjs?activeTab=readme

cleos expects a bit different structure of json. 
something like this:

```
transfer = await eos.transfer('inita', 'initb', '1.0000 SYS', '')
transferTransaction = transfer.transaction

...

// cleos version:
const cleosTransaction = transferTransaction.transaction
cleosTransaction.signatures = transferTransaction.signatures
const json = JSON.stringify(cleosTransaction)
// cleos push transaction $json
```

Answer (score -1):

Each transaction should have expiration time, this exception means that your ref_block time greater than your expiration. You can fix it, by increase expiration time.

Comment: expiration time 1 hour in the future

Comment: You should check not "future time", but ref_block time!

Comment: well actually i do exactly that.

Comment: Ok, what is "max-transaction-time" in your config?